# Flip a bitmap horizontally and draw to specific part of canvas

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap

How do I draw this bitmap to the canvas in the exact same placement, but flipped horizontally? The matrix documentation is not exactly verbose. Here is the initial drawing:

```
canvas.DrawBitmap (_ballBmpRight, ParentView._ballX, ParentView._ballY, null);
```

My attempt to flip the bitmap:

```
flipHorizontalMatrix = new Matrix();
            flipHorizontalMatrix.SetScale(-1,1);
            flipHorizontalMatrix.PostTranslate(_ballBmpRight.Width, 0);
```

Then draw it (this is where I cannot place it in the correct part of the canvas):

```
canvas.DrawBitmap (_ballBmpRight, flipHorizontalMatrix,  null);
```

Comment: where is your `Bitmap` drawn right now?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
BitmapDrawable flip(BitmapDrawable d)
        {
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.PreScale(-1, 1);
            Bitmap src = d.Bitmap;
            Bitmap dst = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.Width, src.Height, m, false);
            //dst.SetDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
            return new BitmapDrawable(dst);
        }
```

Client code for flip:

```
var bd = new BitmapDrawable (_ballBmpRight);
            BitmapDrawable bdFlipped = flip (bd);
            _ballBmpLeft = bdFlipped.Bitmap;
```

Canvas drawing code:

```
canvas.DrawBitmap (_ballBmpLeft, ParentView._ballX, ParentView._ballY, null);
```

Please note the method names have varied slightly (.getBitmap() becomes just .Bitmap) as I am using Xamarin.Android.

Comment: your original solution was **much much better**, dont use any `Bitmap.CreateBitmap` for such Canvas transformations

Comment: @pskink Do you know how to use Canvas.DrawBitmap with a matrix, specifying an X and Y location?

Comment: simply translate your `Matrix`

Comment: @pskink Can you simply translate your answer into code? My bitmap gets drawn at 0,0 on the canvas in my original solution which is why it wasn't working. Cheers.

Comment: as i said you just need to translate your `Matrix`: `flipHorizontalMatrix.PostTranslate(x, y);`

Comment: @pskink I haven't tried it yet. It's a side project, but I'm sure it will work, now that I understand that the parameters for PostTranslate are x and y. Thank you.